# i get authentication error,when trying to test the log in page, i attached everything below .can you guys please help me?

Tags: javascript, firebase

the  error

> **Object { code: "auth/argument-error", message: "signInWithEmailAndPassword failed: First argument "email" must be a valid string.", a: null, stack: "" }
> ​
> a: null
> ​
> code: "auth/argument-error"
> ​
> message: "signInWithEmailAndPassword failed: First argument "email" must be a valid string."
> ​
> stack: ""
> ​
> **

*my code*

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>login Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.2/firebase-app.js"></script>
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.2/firebase-auth.js"></script>
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.2/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.2/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="index.html"><img src="logo.png" alt="logo" /></a>
        <div class="container vh-100">
            <div class="row justify-content-center h-100">
                <div class="card w-25 my-auto shadow">
                    <div class="card-header text-center bg-primary text-white">
                        <h2>Client Login</h2>
                        <h2>form</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <form action="" method="">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="email">Email</label>
                                <input
                                    type="email"
                                    id="email"
                                    class="form-control"
                                    name="email"
                                    required
                                />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="password">Password</label>
                                <input
                                    type="password"
                                    id="password"
                                    placeholder="password"
                                    class="form-control"
                                    name="password"
                                    required
                                />
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="ssn">ssn</label>
                                <input
                                    type="text"
                                    id="ssn"
                                    placeholder="SSN"
                                    class="form-control"
                                    name="ssn"
                                />
                            </div>

                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />

                            <button type="submit" id="submit">submit</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer text-right"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />

        <style>
            img {
                padding-left: 40%;
                padding-right: 40%;

                animation: rotation 2s infinite linear;
            }

            @keyframes rotation {
                100% {
                    transform: rotateY(360deg);
                }
            }
        </style>

        <p>not a user?</p>
        <a href="clientup.html">sign up</a>
        <script>
            var firebaseConfig = {
                apiKey: '******',
                authDomain: '******',
                projectId: '********',
                storageBucket: '*******',
                messagingSenderId: '**********',
                appId: '*******',
                measurementId: '******',
            };

            //import 'firebase/analytics';
            // Initialize Firebase
            firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
            firebase.analytics();

            const db = firebase.firestore();
            const email = document.getElementById('email');
            const password = document.getElementById('password');
            const lol = document.getElementById('submit');
            lol.addEventListener('click', function () {
                firebase
                    .auth()
                    .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                    .then((userCredential) => {
                        // Signed in
                        var user = userCredential.user;
                        // ...
                    })
                    .catch((error) => {
                        var errorCode = error.code;
                        var errorMessage = error.message;
                    });
            });
            var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

            if (user) {
                // User is signed in.
                window.location.replace('clientdash.html');
            } else {
                // No user is signed in.
                console.log('no users found');
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `const lol = document.getElementById('submit');` ? Hope this is not going to production!

Comment: why is there something wrong?  

Comment: Other developers will just not probably take you very seriously if you name your variables `lol`. Use variable names that indicate what the variable is used for.

Comment: oh.. thank you for the suggestion :D, I have too much sense of humor

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementById('email')
```

That's a javascript object.

You want its value:

```
document.getElementById('email').value
```

Didn't watch the rest of the code.

Comment: Same for password.

Comment: @Tawhid, you should provide error details instead.